# How to pass std::move through a templated argument

Tags: c++, templates, types, move

Often times I will have a templated function where I try to pass a && type. Problem is, if I put std::move as the argument, I get an error such as this one:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'doThing(void (*)(int&&), std::remove_reference<int&>::type)'
```

The code that generated that particular error is as following:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
void doThing(void (*thing)(T), T input)
{
    thing(input);
}

void exampleThing(int&& someData)
{someData++;}

int main()
{
    int x, y = 5;
    exampleThing(std::move(x));             //compiles fine
    doThing(&exampleThing, std::move(y));   //error as shown above
}
```

So, how would I pass an argument to a template as a move?

Comment: I would try using a separate template parameter to define the first parameter to `doThing()`, and then use enable_if_t to check that it's callable with the 2nd parameter as a value.

Answer (score 4):

Issue with

`template<typename T>
void doThing(void (*thing)(T), T input)`

is that `T` is deduced from 2 places, and should be identical.

Simpler to split in 2 template parameters:

```
template <typename Arg, typename T>
void doThing(void (*thing)(Arg), T&& input)
{
    thing(std::forward<T>(input));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d25df8b777afefc1)

Another option is to allow deduction only at one place:

I use [std::type_identity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (C++20) for this, but can be trivially re-implemented for previous version.

```
template <typename Arg>
void doThing(void (*thing)(Arg), std::type_identity_t<Arg> input)
{
    thing(std::forward<Arg>(input));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1ed9bd66e24d14b)